# I have a piece of code that works, but is very inefficient. It can probably be improved, but I don't understand how "return" works

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've patched together a code that grabs the string from the activecell and loops it through a range until it finds a match, then it returns the cell adjacent to it. It works the way I want it to, but it is a little slow and the log shows that the script returns the value of the adjacent cell about 30 times (as many as it exists I believe). Since I am going to increase the range later, this delay may end up being a problem.

I am 90% sure that you can fix this just by knowing how the return statement works (I've inserted a Return statement and then the log looked correct, but I had no idea how to actually set the value from that return statement)

```
//------ Step 1: Take value in activecell assuming it is in column 2 and below row 3.

function onEdit () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var database = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
  var lists = ss.getSheetByName("Studentinfo");
  var activeCell = database.getActiveCell();

  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() >3) {

    var activeStudent = activeCell.getValue();
    Logger.log(activeStudent)
  }

//------ Step 2: Search lists for value of activeStudent & store value

  var row = lists.getRange(4, 1,lists.getLastRow(),2).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i<row.length;i++) {

    if (row[i][1] == activeStudent)
// here is probably where Return row[i][0] should be?
    var studentClass = row[i][0];
    Logger.log(studentClass)
      }

//------ Step 3: Take the value and set it to activeCell offset (0,-1)

  activeCell.offset(0,-1).setValue(studentClass); 


}
```

Comment: `return` just ends the function and `return`s a value.

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is to stop executing the script once the match has been found, then you have two options:

1. Yes, just return something once you've found the match:

```
for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (row[i][1] == activeStudent) {
        var studentClass = row[i][0];
        Logger.log(studentClass);
        activeCell.offset(0,-1).setValue(studentClass); 
        return studentClass;
    }
}
```

By calling `return` you make it possible to reference the value calculated by your `onEdit` function somewhere else, like `var studentClass = onEdit();`.

Because `return` finishes running of your function, you'll need to set your values into the spreadsheet before calling it.

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

2. As I don't think it's the case, you could break your loop once you have the match:

```
for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (row[i][1] == activeStudent) {
        var studentClass = row[i][0];
        Logger.log(studentClass);
        break;
    }
}
```

`break` makes the function to finish the loop at any given point without waiting until all the elements are iterated but it doesn't finish the function itself so you can set your values outside the loop.

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break